# PivotItem ScrollViewer can't scroll down

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, scrollview, pivotitem

PivotItem ScrollViewer can't scroll down

For whatever the reason just won't scroll down when content that is bound inside the pivot item is longer than the height of the page. I tried adding a grid inside the pivotitem with height set to auto, but to no avail.

```
<controls:PivotItem>
                    <controls:PivotItem.Header>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Name="TextBlockPropertyDetail" FontSize="31" Text="Property Detail" />
                        </Grid>
                    </controls:PivotItem.Header>
                    <ScrollViewer>
                            <Grid Height="Auto">
                                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Property Id" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="Black" />
                                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,41,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="County" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="Black" />
                                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,77,0,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="Parcel Number" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="Black" />
                                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,113,0,0" Name="textBlock4" Text="Market Value" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="Black" />
                                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,149,0,0" Name="textBlock5" Text="Document Image" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="Black" />
                                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,185,0,0" Name="textBlock6" Text="Value Range" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="Black" />
                                <TextBlock Height="30" Margin="12,221,279,0" Name="textBlock7" Text="Insured" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" />
                                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,257,0,0" Name="textBlock8" Text="Case Number" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="Black" />
                                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,293,0,0" Name="textBlock9" Text="Recording Date" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="Black" />
                                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,329,0,0" Name="textBlock10" Text="Recording Book" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="Black" />
                                <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,365,0,0" Name="textBlock11" Text="Recording Page" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="Black" />
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,5,0,0" Name="tbkPropertyId" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,41,0,0" Name="tbkCounty" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,77,0,0" Name="tbkParcelNo" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,113,0,0" Name="tbkMarketValue" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,149,0,0" Name="tbkDocumentImage" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,185,0,0" Name="tbkValueRange" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,221,0,0" Name="tbkInsured" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,257,0,0" Name="tbkCaseNo" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,293,0,0" Name="tbkRecordingDate" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,329,0,0" Name="tbkRecordingBook" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,365,0,0" Name="tbkRecordingPage" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                            </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </controls:PivotItem>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Stackpanel in the grid Element and try this.

```
  <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="first" Height="580" >
            <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
            <ScrollViewer>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Property Id" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="County" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="Parcel Number" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBlock4" Text="Market Value" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBlock5" Text="Document Image" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBlock6" Text="Value Range" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" Margin="12,5,279,0" Name="textBlock7" Text="Insured" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBlock8" Text="Case Number" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBlock9" Text="Recording Date" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBlock10" Text="Recording Book" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBlock11" Text="Recording Page" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-385,0,0" Name="tbkPropertyId" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-350,0,0" Name="tbkCounty" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-315,0,0" Name="tbkParcelNo" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-275,0,0" Name="tbkMarketValue" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-240,0,0" Name="tbkDocumentImage" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-205,0,0" Name="tbkValueRange" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-170,0,0" Name="tbkInsured" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-135,0,0" Name="tbkCaseNo" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-100,0,0" Name="tbkRecordingDate" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-65,0,0" Name="tbkRecordingBook" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-30,0,0" Name="tbkRecordingPage" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBlsock1" Text="Property Id" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textsBlock2" Text="County" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBslock3" Text="Parcel Number" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textsBlock4" Text="Market Value" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textsBlock5" Text="Document Image" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textsBlock6" Text="Value Range" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBlocsk7" Text="Insured" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBslock8" Text="Case Number" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBslock9" Text="Recording Date" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBlsock10" Text="Recording Book" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,5,0,0" Name="textBsock11" Text="Recording Page" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Foreground="White" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-380,0,0" Name="tbkPropsertyId" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-345,0,0" Name="tbkCosunty" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-310,0,0" Name="tbkPasrcelNo" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-275,0,0" Name="tbkMsarketValue" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-240,0,0" Name="tbkDsocumentImage" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-205,0,0" Name="s" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-170,0,0" Name="tsbkInsured" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-135,0,0" Name="tbskCaseNo" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-100,0,0" Name="tbskRecordingDate" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-70,0,0" Name="tbksRecordingBook" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="241,-35,0,0" Name="tbkRsecordingPage" Text="Loading..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </controls:PivotItem>
 </controls:Pivot>
```

And I hope you will get the Solution.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, Thanks for your suggestion. I have included the StackPanel, after that all the controls inside StackPanel aligned to center. I need 11 TextBlocks in left side and 11 in right side.

Comment: can i update ?
or you will complete the margins problems ?
please tell me. if you can't done then i will upadate the answer..
can i update the answer or you will solve the margin problems.?

Comment: Solution updated..
you just copy this code.
you will get the requested answer.
And Please Upvote if you find the useful Answers

Comment: Thanks for your update. I got the requested answer. Can you give me a guidance to solve margin problems? I am new in XAML.

Comment: oh.
Yes.!!
refer this msdn documentation.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx.